# symbol could not be resolve on makefile project with eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a makefile project. I can build it in the command line. But when I add this project to eclipse and build as makefile project. The binary output file is created and run normally, but eclipse gets an error: symbol stderr (or NULL, bool, etc...) could not be resolved.
How can I solve these problems?